# Is it possible to use tokens for API and cookies for get Razor page or Controller Action in the same app with using identity server?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, identity

I have an SPA project with .net core 3.1 & identity server and react.i want to Authorize API with token and Authorize Controller Action or Razor Pages with cookies in Get Request, Is it possible to use both of them in same app?
For example, I want admin area to be Authorize with cookie and the admin to have access to its views by cookie but User area works with react and Api by token.

Startup.cs:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
                {
                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(
                            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        
                    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        
                    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                        .AddApiAuthorization<IdentityUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
    
                    builder.Services.ConfigureExternalCookie(options => {
                        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                        options.Cookie.SameSite = (SameSiteMode.Unspecified); 
                    });
        
                    builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
                        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                        options.Cookie.SameSite = (SameSiteMode.Unspecified); 
                    });
        
                    services.AddAuthentication()
                        .AddIdentityServerJwt();
        
                    services.AddControllersWithViews();
                    services.AddRazorPages();
                    services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
        
                  
                    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
                    {
                        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
                    });
    }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("adminArea", "{area=Admin}/{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to authorize with different auth schemes in an ASP.Net Core application, you just have to specify it on the [Authorize] tag that you call before the method.

First you have to add both authentications at the `services.AddAuthentication()` call.

Then, lets say that you want your method to authenticate with JWT token:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = 
JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

On the other hand, if you want it to authenticate with a cookie:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

You can check more of how it works at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1.